# Ionic Cordova pushPlugin error on processMessage?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework

Any idea what would cause this problem? I loaded correctly ngCordova and the $cordovaPush but I get this error which is driving me nuts

```
    processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
processMessage failed: Stack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at eval (eval at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1021:26), <anonymous>:1:74)
    at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1021:13)
    at Function.androidExec.processMessages (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1091:13)
    at pollOnce (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:956:17)
    at pollOnceFromOnlineEvent (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:946:5)
processMessage failed: Message: Jjavascript:angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector().get('$cordovaPush').onNotification({"event":"registered","regid":"APA91bFCuwFAveicLbPtR[...]"})
```

Comment: angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector() is undefined

Comment: @hanh Thanks. It is because I manually start the app via angular.bootstrap. Therefore ng-app is never defined I can't figure a way around this... I start manually because I have a piece of code that runs first to get the CSRF_token from the server and then injects it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, not the right solution yet (- different topic -). 
Basically cordova wants to use ng-app however it is not set in my app since I manually bootstrap the app because I set constants before. I need to find a way to do both now

Answer (score 0):

Just set ecb in your config like this:

"ecb": "angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$cordovaPush').onNotification"